# Sql select union same table

Tags: sql-server, join, union

Regards

I have the following tables

**Client**

```
id, name, saler1, saler2, saler3, dateSale...
```

**Personnel**

```
id, name...
```

My query is

```
select S1.*, S2.* 
from Client C 
left join Personnel S1.id on = C.saler1
left Join Personnel S2.id on = C.saler2
```

My result is

```
S1.id, S1.name ... S2.id, S2.name
```

but I want only one column for example `Personnel`

```
|id | name |
|sa1| name |
|sa2| name |
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are asking but from the query you have already written I think you are after something like this.....

```
Select *
FROM (
SELECT id, name, saler1 AS Saler, dateSale FROM Client Where saler1 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, name, saler2 AS Saler, dateSale FROM Client Where saler2 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, name, saler3 AS Saler, dateSale FROM Client Where saler3 IS NOT NULL
) C
Left join Personnel P  on P.id  = C.saler
```

Since this is what you want another sleek way of doing the same thing would be to use `UNPIVOT` something like ....

```
Select P.* , up.id, up.dated
FROM Client UNPIVOT (
                      Salers for Saler IN (Saler1,Saler2,Saler3)
                     )up
LEFT JOIN Personnel P ON up.Salers = P.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for an Union All

```
select S1.* From Client C Left join Personnel S1.id on = C.saler1
UNION ALL
select S1.* From Client C Left join Personnel S1.id on = C.saler2
```